# Specifying sourcepath in jdb, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, jdb

I have a java project in which the file system is as follows:
I have 3 directories: *bin*, *src*, and *lib*.

- *src* contains my **.java* files
- *bin* contains my **.class* files (compiled using the files in *src*)
- *lib* contains a few **.jar* files imported by most of the *src* files

I am learning how to use jdb but every time I try and use the list command it just says that the source file cannot be found. I am running the following command from within my bin directory:

```sh
jdb -classpath ../lib/*:. -sourcepath ../src envelope.Envelope
```

where my main method is contained within the Envelope class which is part of the envelope package, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you source files directly in `src` or are they in `src/main/java`?

Comment: Which version of java are you using ?

Comment: Java version 1.6.0_27

Comment: Ran into the same problem. I needed to set the source path to location of the package source not the actual dir of the files. So my source was in <project root>/src/com/test/testproject. I set the -sourcepath to <project root>/src.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this one is very old, but maybe someone will be still interested in it

Let's say we have file

```
package mypackage;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

and layout of the project follows

```
jdb_test/
├── src
│   └── mypackage
│       └── Main.java
└── target
    └── mypackage
        └── Main.class
```

class file was compiled using:

```
javac -sourcepath src -d target src/mypackage/Main.java
# if you have multiple files, you can always do
find . -name "*.java" -exec javac -sourcepath src -d target {} \;
```

Then, being inside *jdb_test* directory, we can call

```
jdb -sourcepath src -classpath target mypackage.Main
```

and debug the code

```
Initializing jdb ...
> stop in mypackage.Main.main
Deferring breakpoint mypackage.Main.main.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
> run
run mypackage.Main
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>
VM Started: Set deferred breakpoint mypackage.Main.main

Breakpoint hit: "thread=main", mypackage.Main.main(), line=5 bci=0
5        System.out.println("Hello world");

main[1] list
1    package mypackage;
2
3    public class Main {
4      public static void main(String [] arg) {
5 =>     System.out.println("Hello world");
6      }
7    }
main[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same issue as SO, and in addition to the provided solution, I want to point out, you need to execute JDB from correct directory. If your class belongs to any package, e.g. class `MainActivity` belongs to package `org.gradle.samples`, then your project folder contains the following directory:

```
yourProject/
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── java
│           └── org
│               └── gradle
│                   └── samples
│                       └── MainActivity.java
```

Then you have to execute `jdb` from `<pathToYourProject>/src/main/java`, where JDB `-sourcepath` is `<pathToYourProject>/src/main/java` as well.

The `list` command will not work if you execute JDB from a different location, even if you have defined the correct `-sourcepath`. Or even if you change the the source path within the JDB console via `use` command.

Answer (score 0):

There is an on-the-fly alternate way.

"sourcepath" is also a command within jdb itself.  So let's say you've already attached/set breakpoint/run, and are getting this error and don't want to start over.
Just type  `sourcepath /path/to/srcdir` and it should be happy from there on.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
cd <projectdir>/src/main/java  #this is for AndroidStudio builds
jdb <args>
```

and in ~/.jdbrc

```
sourcepath .
```